# Document attribute stays empty for Invoice class

Tags: api, exact-online

When trying to fetch the [SalesInvoices](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=SalesInvoiceSalesInvoices) class from the Exact Online REST API all the relevant document entries stay empty. I'm using the [Exact Online Python SDK](https://github.com/ossobv/exactonline) for fetching these SalesInvoices.

The code used:

```
return self.api.invoices.filter(
    filter="Customer eq guid'{}'".format(self.api.relations.get(relation_code=relation_code)['ID']),
    top=10,
    orderby='EntryNumber desc')
```

Which gives the following response:

```
"Document": null,
"DocumentNumber": null,
"DocumentSubject": null,
```

While the SalesInvoice does have a generated document:

[image: invoice]

I have contacted Exact Online support but so far have gotten no reply

Comment: How can I see from the screenshot that the sales invoice has an associated document?

Comment: Document has an icon attached to it, if there is no document this stays empty. I don't have a lot of knowledge on Exact Online so I could be wrong

Comment: What is the actual REST request made (URL) (so what Python SDK makes from it)? And are the other fields and values present?

Comment: `v1/1749519/salesentry/SalesEntries?$filter=Customer%20eq%20guid%27e9ae2271-d4c3-44ad-a0b0-0816ac63ace9%27&$top=10&$orderby=EntryNumber%20desc`

Comment: You are fetching `SalesEntries`, not `SalesInvoices`.

Comment: When using `v1/1749519/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices?$filter=InvoiceTo%20eq%20guid%27e9ae2271-d4c3-44ad-a0b0-0816ac63ace9%27&$top=10&$orderby=OrderNumber%20desc` the document attribute is empty

Comment: Can you show it is actually there in EOL?

Comment: Here is the response that I get when using salesinvoice/SalesInvoices: https://i.imgur.com/B4ciLDJ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See picture. The Document, DocumentNumber and DocumentSubject are available in ExactOnlineREST..SalesInvoices:

[image: SalesInvoice with Document]

But... the evil is in the detail, because [documentation](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=SalesInvoiceSalesInvoices) reads:

`Document that is manually linked to the invoice`

And indeed, this field only gets a value when you manually add a document to the invoice such as before printing it.

When you need all documents and files attached to the sales invoice, please use something like:

```
select dat.url
from   salesinvoices sie
join   exactonlinerest..documents dct
on     dct.salesinvoicenumber = sie.invoicenumber
and    dct.type=10 /* Optional to improve performance. */
join   ExactOnlineREST.Documents.DocumentAttachments dat
on     dat.document = dct.id
```

Please change this into Python code, but the syntax and join order and arguments are clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't find a way to execute this query using the REST api. And using the Online SQL Editor I can't execute JOIN queries.

Comment: And I still don't get why the webinterface has the documents (generated invoice PDF) linked in every list and invoice overview but I can't get it out of the API?

Comment: Just translate the calls by hand into REST calls, such as $filter=type eq 10 etc. Or install Invantive Control or so, execute the query and then query 'select * from sessionios' to see the actual REST calls made and copy these into your code.

Comment: The generated invoice PDF is in the API for documentattachments. Join from salesinvoices to documents to documentattachments. There you will find the URL and then get that one using the same channel. With our sql that would be httpget(dat.url), in your case just HTTP GET over the previously established HTTP connection with OAuth in place. Please note that there is also a knowledge base on Exact Online itself. It is better then the support channel when you are not a qualified app partner.